# lComo puedo enviar un correo directamente desde mi app?

Tags: android

Hola Gente Queria saber como puedo enviar un email a una cuenta electronica desde mi app sin pasar por el medio de gmail...! , He visto varios tutoriales que envian mails pero todos pasan par el medio de gmail.. Yo me gustaria hacerlo desde mi aplicacion segun el activity que arme ...
HAY OTRA FORMA PARA HACERLO ?? MUCHAS GRACIAS 
Intente asi pero no me llego ningun mensaje al destinatario

```
  protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    etContent = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etContent);
    etRecipient = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etRecipient);
    btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
    btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendMessage();
        }
    });
}

private void sendMessage() {
    final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(ActivityMain.this);
    dialog.setTitle("Sending Email");
    dialog.setMessage("Please wait");
    dialog.show();
    Thread sender = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("email_receiver@gmail.com", "password");
                sender.sendMail("EmailSender App",
                        etContent.getText().toString(),
                        "email_receiver@gmail.com",
                        etRecipient.getText().toString());
                dialog.dismiss();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("mylog", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
    sender.start();
}
```

Comment: Muestra lo que haz intentado, el sitio es para prestar ayuda con problemas concretos de programación. [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: No es posible enviar correos electronicos sin utilizar un servidor SMTP. Saludos!

Comment: Gracias por sus respuestas , ahi , edite mi pregunta ...con el codigo que intente

Comment: Puedes crear un servicio Web donde le pases los campos y que este sea el encargado de enviar el correo.